# why my ajax cannot send any data to server?

Tags: jquery, ajax, database

there is a problem when i want to use ajax to send data to server. here my script maybe there some wrong with my script. actually, i have try it with manual way (php) and it works

```
    $('#frm_input').on('submit',function(){
    var data = new FormData();

    //Form data
    var form_data = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.each(form_data, function (key, input) {
        data.append(input.name, input.value);
    });

    //profil
    var profil = $('input[name="gbr_profil"]')[0].files;
    data.append("gbr_profil", profil[0]);


    //File data
    var file_data = $('input[name="galeri[]"]')[0].files;
    for (var i = 0; i < file_data.length; i++) {
        data.append("galeri[]", file_data[i]);
    }


    $.ajax({
        url: "template/proses.php?p=tambah",
        method: "post",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#msg').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

i don't know what problem there

Comment: What happens? Anything on the console? Don't make people guess.

Comment: Put datatype json on ajax call section.

Comment: if i put datatype json, then what i have to do with server side (on proses.php) ??